# Meaning and grammar of 매달리다 and hand gestures

Tags: vocabulary, korean-culture

In this song lyrics there is the phrase "이제와 울고불고 매달리지마". What I can get from the sentence is something on the lines of "quit crying around", but I am not sure. Also, what role does the particle 와 play in this sentence?

Additionally, what does Dara´s hand gesture (appearing on the screen at 3:55, slightly moving the hand against the chin) convey? Does it have any special meaning in Korean culture?

https://youtu.be/4MgAxMO1KD0?t=233

Answer (score 1, accepted):

매달리다 means begging somebody. So 매달리지 마 means 'stop begging me'.

와 is an inflectional form of the verb '오다' which means 'come' in English. 오다 can be used in various sentences with slightly different meanings.

Basically, 오다 means "Someone or something moves and gets closer to the point where I am." It can also mean that a specific moment or a season has arrived.

Hence, 이제 와 means 'now' or 'at this belated time'. Considering the context of the lyrics, the phrase also means 'eventually' or 'finally. So the sentence of the lyrics means "Finally, you are crying and begging me but stop it because it's too late to change my mind."

And I checked the MV of 2NE1 and checked the gesture of Sandara, but I don't find a special meaning from it. As a native Korean, I think it is just a meaningless gesture she made.